# Get object version with JaVers

Tags: javers

I'm using JaVers 5.6.3 with Spring Boot 2.1. Saving history is working fine and I also can read object changes.

I use this code:

```
List<Change> changes = javers.findChanges(jqlQuery.build());
```

My problem is that the result contains only the commit id, but not the object version. In the database there is a `jv_snapshot.version` field, that contains the real object version.

How can I get it in my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the version using snapshot for example:

```
List<CdoSnapshot> snapshots =  javers.findSnapshots(jqlQuery.build());
snapshots.forEach(snapshot -> {
    System.out.println(snapshot.getVersion());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this helps or not
but you can get whole entity with its version

First get the shadow and then try to get snapshot from the committed. As given in the code

```
 List<Shadow<YourObject>> shadows=        javers.findShadows(QueryBuilder.byInstance(optionalObject.get()).build());

 List<CdoSnapshot> changes=javers.findSnapshots(QueryBuilder.byInstanceId(id,YourObject.class).withCommitId(shadow.get(0).getCommitId()).build());
```

In this way, you can get version of each entity, let me know if you find some better way.